# PostgreSQL invalid input syntax for type integer while updating table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am newbie to PostgreSQL and getting below error while updating table in PostgreSQL.

````
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "@vendortypeid"
LINE 2:    set vendortypeid = '@vendortypeid',
                              ^
QUERY:  update public.vendormaster vm
         set vendortypeid = '@vendortypeid',
         email = '@email', misbapsid = '@misbapsid', businessname = '@businessname', taxid = '@taxid', 
         primarycontactname = '@primarycontactname', primarycontactemail = '@primarycontactemail', additionalname = '@additionalname', 
         primaryaddress1 = '@primaryaddress1', primaryaddress2 = '@primaryaddress2', primarycountryid = '@primarycountryid', 
         primarystateid = '@primarystateid', primaryzipcode = '@primaryzipcode', ischild = '@ischild', parentid = '@parentid', 
         isactive = '@isactive', mobileno = '@mobileno',
        createdby='@createdby',createdon='@createdon', isdeleted='@isdeleted', deletedby='@deletedby', deletedon='@deletedon', 
        updatedby='@updatedby',updatedon='@updatedon', primarycityid = '@primarycityid', status = '@status'
         where vm.vendorid = vendorids
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insertorupdatevendormaster(bigint,integer,character,bigint,character,integer,character,character,character,character,character,integer,integer,integer,boolean,bigint,boolean,character,integer,date,boolean,integer,date,integer,date,integer,character) line 15 at SQL statement
SQL state: 22P02```

Thanks
````

Comment: PL/pgSQL does not use `@` to reference parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes denote string literals. If you're referring to arguments passed to the function, you should not surround them with quotes:

```sql
UPDATE PUBLIC.vendormaster vm
SET    vendortypeid = @vendortypeid,
       email = @email,
       misbapsid = @misbapsid,
       businessname = @businessname,
       taxid = @taxid,
       primarycontactname = @primarycontactname,
       primarycontactemail = @primarycontactemail,
       additionalname = @additionalname,
       primaryaddress1 = @primaryaddress1,
       primaryaddress2 = @primaryaddress2,
       primarycountryid = @primarycountryid,
       primarystateid = @primarystateid,
       primaryzipcode = @primaryzipcode,
       ischild = @ischild,
       parentid = @parentid,
       isactive = @isactive,
       mobileno = @mobileno,
       createdby = @createdby,
       createdon = @createdon,
       isdeleted = @isdeleted,
       deletedby = @deletedby,
       deletedon = @deletedon,
       updatedby = @updatedby,
       updatedon = @updatedon,
       primarycityid = @primarycityid,
       status = @status
WHERE  vm.vendorid = vendorids
```

Comment: Thanks @mureinik, it worked for me, also I stored all parameter values into variable and then assign it to column name in update query as it was giving me ambiguous column name.